# How to resolve ECL components in rich text fields

Tags: dxa, rtf, dxa-1.5

Not able to bind Rich Text field to Model if I am embedding an ECL image in a RTF field. Getting below error:

> Unable to map field 'description' to property of type 'Sdl.Web.Common.Models.RichText'. ---> Sdl.Web.Common.DxaException: No semantic mapping found between Schema 295 (http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core:ExternalContentLibraryStubSchemamm) and model type 'Sdl.Web.Common.Models.MediaItem'
>   Sdl.Web.Common.DxaException: Unable to map field 'description' to property of type 'Sdl.Web.Common.Models.RichText'. ---> Sdl.Web.Common.DxaException: No semantic mapping found between Schema 295 (http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core:ExternalContentLibraryStubSchemamm) and model type 'Sdl.Web.Common.Models.MediaItem'
>      at DynamicModule.ns.Wrapped_IRichTextProcessor_6356ea62ef3f4433b0f047b3f93feb12.ProcessRichText(String xhtml, Localization localization)
>      at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultModelBuilder.MapFieldValues(IField field, Type modelType, Boolean multival, MappingData mapData) in D:\Repository\LocalDevstage27March\master\source code\web application\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Mapping\DefaultModelBuilder.cs:line 622
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultModelBuilder.MapFieldValues(IField field, Type modelType, Boolean multival, MappingData mapData) in D:\Repository\LocalDevstage27March\master\source code\web application\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Mapping\DefaultModelBuilder.cs:line 653
>      at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultModelBuilder.CreateViewModel(MappingData mappingData) in D:\Repository\LocalDevstage27March\master\source code\web application\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Mapping\DefaultModelBuilder.cs:line 400
>      at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultModelBuilder.BuildEntityModel(EntityModel& entityModel, IComponent component, Type baseModelType, Localization localization) in D:\Repository\LocalDevstage27March\master\source code\web application\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Mapping\DefaultModelBuilder.cs:line 191
>      at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultModelBuilder.BuildEntityModel(EntityModel& entityModel, IComponentPresentation cp, Localization localization) in D:\Repository\LocalDevstage27March\master\source code\web application\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Mapping\DefaultModelBuilder.cs:line 144
>      at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.ModelBuilderPipeline.CreateEntityModel(IComponentPresentation cp, Localization localization) in D:\Repository\LocalDevstage27March\master\source code\web application\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Mapping\ModelBuilderPipeline.cs:line 100
>      at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultModelBuilder.BuildPageModel(PageModel& pageModel, IPage page, IEnumerable`1 includes, Localization localization) in D:\Repository\LocalDevstage27March\master\source code\web application\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Mapping\DefaultModelBuilder.cs:line 76

Comment: Please provide the error in detail from Site.Log. Also confirm if your model is registered in your <Module>AreaRegistration ? if not then register that first and check it again.

Comment: Although I think Sayantan already provided the answer to your question, I'm wondering why you're using a custom build (given the file paths in the stack trace) and what that `DynamicModule.ns.Wrapped_IRichTextProcessor` line in the stack trace is about (I would expect `DefaultRichTextProcessor` there)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you are using DXA Media Manager module and you have already created a Model for the Media Manager item, if not then add a Model in your project. Here is the sample for that;

```
[SemanticEntity(CoreVocabulary, EntityName = "ExternalContentLibraryStubSchema-mm", Prefix = "a", Public = true)]
public class MultiMediaModel : MediaManagerDistribution
{ 
}
```

And add entry for your Model in `ModuleAreaRegistration.cs` like;

```
RegisterViewModel(typeof(MultiMediaModel));
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I would strongly recommend to use the Media Manager Module instead of "reinventing the wheel".

Comment: @RickPannekoek yes I agree. This is just a workaround.

Comment: BTW: the example shows how to create a custom subclass of `MediaManagerDistribution` which is a View Model from the MM Module. So, it's not an alternative for the MM Module, nor does it add anything. I'm aware that a custom subclass is currently needed if (and only if) you're using retrofit mode: https://github.com/sdl/dxa-modules/issues/23

Comment: @RickPannekoek Yes! Basically I am creating a subclass of MediaManagerDistribution and  registering it. Actually I am using the same type of implementation in current application as well (without retrofit mode) because there we have added some additional field in metadata design of MM schema  and I don't want to change anything in the default modle. I am just trying to understand is this approach not recommended ?? then may be I can change the approach.

Comment: Creating your own subclass of `MediaManagerDistribution` with additional properties/methods/annotations is fine (indeed much better than changing the MM Module itself), but in the above example the subclass doesn't add any of those and hence is not needed.